# How to create a smaller subset of a large file using spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a bunch of large related files. I want to generate smaller files with subset of the data from the larger files. How can I acheive that using apache spark?

I am able to load these files, apply transformations and create a subset of records in a dataset. I am able to do a `df.show()` to view these in the driver sysout. But I couldn't find a way to write these into file.

All I want is the output of df.show in a file. Spark is already aggregating the results to driver program to display this data. Why isn't there a way to write these to a file!

I see similar questions asked. But don't see any definite answer. 
`coalesce(1)` won't work for me since its too large to save in a single partition memory.

If writing a file is not possible, what other option do I have to get this dataset in a place like database or something like that? I tried S3, but it takes a really long time and generates huge amount of files.

Answer (score 1):

Just `limit` the data:

```
df: DataFrame

df.limit(10).write.format(...).save(...)
```

Comment: That will be spread across all the worker nodes. Also my df is already small enough. So dont need to limit.